# Download a file from location using curl command into a child directory and save with a different name

Tags: curl

I am using `curl` to download the file from a url. Currently I am able to download the file as it is in the current directory using the `curl` command like

```
curl -O http://path/to/url/17.01.24/smcfs-17.01.24.ear
```

This downloads the file alright but saves it in the current directory by the name `smcfs-17.01.24.ear` as expected. However I would like to download and save this file by creating a directory inside the current directory with bash script like

```
if [[ ! -d "$4" ]]; then
    mkdir "$4"
    curl -O http://path/to/url/$4/smcfs-$4.ear   #I would like curl to fucntion like I said here    
fi
```

**NOTE**: In above code snippet I am taking the version number i.e `17.01.24` as `4rth` argument of script

The expected output will be that curl download the file `smcfs-17.01.24.ear` by the name `smcfs.ear` in the directory `17.01.24` which is the subdirectory of the current diretory.

I would like to achieve this without going into the subdirectory, using curl to download and then coming back to the current directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the following to download a file into a directory with a given name

```
curl "http://path/to/url/$4/smcfs-$4.ear" --output "$4/smcfs.ear"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain the behaviour you’re after by dropping the `-O`:

```
curl "http://path/to/url/$4/smcfs-$4.ear" > "$4/smcfs.ear"
```

(after the `mkdir`). By default `curl` outputs the content it downloads to its standard output; `-O` tells it to save it to a file matching the remote name.